# how to use refresh html header through php through shell

Tags: php, html, shell, header

I wrote a php script that refresh automatically to do a long process.
To do that, I use:

```
header('refresh: '.$refresh_time);
```

*The time between every refresh is changed depending of what happened*

It works well on a classic browser but I need to execute this script from shell now.
To do that, I tried:

```
php my_php_script.php
```

But this don't works as it execute the script only 1 time (yep, no refresh here).

So, is it possible to use the headers sent in php by calling the script in a command shell?

- If yes, please enlighten my knowledge.
- If no, BE DOOMED!!!! Damn, I'll have change my code!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd guess it's not possible since that executing this script from the command line won't send the headers to the browser.

Comment: you can use `curl` command and access an url(in your case php) with headers.

Comment: The refresh header is parsed by your browser. The browser requests the site again after the interval set in `header('refresh: '.$refresh_time);` elapses. If you execute the file without a full browser it will not get refreshed.

Comment: @Jigar: So I have to do a shell script that recall curl -i my_php_script.php depending of the refresh header got from the previous curl -i my_php_script.php?

Comment: @ByteHamster: I have tried lynx without much success :(

Comment: I think you will have to make things recursive in the script, if the refresh is dependent on previous executions. (I am assuming you don't want that script to stop any day, you will have to kill it to stop then). If you are planning that, see to it that memory is emptied after every loop.

Comment: @LittleGecko The `curl` approach seems the most promising

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I answer my question but I would like to thanks you all for the helpfull tips.

As HTML headers can't be used by calling php though shell, I wrote a script that get the refresh header sent and sleep the time needed before calling again the php script.

```
#!/bin/bash

my_bash_function()
{
  response="$(curl -vs http://localhost/my_php_script.php) 2>&1"
  refresh_regex="refresh:[[:space:]]([0-9]+)\s*"
  numeric_regex="^[0-9]+$"

  if [[ "$response" =~ $refresh_regex ]] ; then
    refresh="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    if [[ "$refresh" =~ $numeric_regex ]] ; then
      sleep $refresh
      my_bash_function
    fi
  fi
}

my_bash_function
```

That way, it allow me to not change the php script and simply use it as the curl or php command could respond to the refresh header.

Am I wrong ?

Edit: I was wrong! curl -I don't seams to execute properly the php code but only what the headers need. curl -vs seams to works but to get the header output, I had to add 2>&1

*Credits: Jigar, Pavan Jiwnani*

Comment: There are 2 numeric tests but I prefere having 1 in more than having something going through the 1st test for some reason (that proove my confidence in my regular expression skill)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using shell command in php file You can use the following code it will do the exact same thing in shell.

```
$refresh_time = rand(2,10);
sleep($refresh_time);
$command     = "php my_php_script.php > /dev/null &";
shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: Not bad but the refresh delay depend on what is going to happen... and it is the php script that knows what it's going to do...

Comment: @LittleGecko This was just for the demonstration, instead of rand function you can use your php logic and if required you can also pass the arguments through shell command

Answer (score 0):

On Linux System, you can use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). And on Windows, you can use [windows schedule task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task).

Basically you can tell them when to execute your script. Every minute, day, week, etc.

Search on Google for more details.

Tricky part would be to change the time interval, can't help you much with that. Will surely let you know in case I find a solution for the same.

Comment: The refresh used is more between 2 and 10 seconds than a minute. It will take too long to execute the whole process if the cron is done every minutes

Comment: Ah. Yes, I doubt if cron goes down than a minute. Ignore my answer :)

Comment: But I like the curl idea :)